# Monitoring Greenplum 6 with pgAdmin

Tags: pgadmin, greenplum, pgadmin-4

I could monitor Greenplum 5 with pgAdmin dashboard. However, it seems that it is not working after upgrading to Greenplum 6. May I know if anyone could still monitor Greenplum 6 with pgAdmin? If not, appreciate if anyone can suggest an alternative. Best regards,
William

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pgadmin isn't supported by GPDB anymore. It hasn't been supported since `5.2`.